# VS Code não está fazendo comentários. Alguém já se deparou com esse problema?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Quando adiciono trechos de comentários no código o VS Code não os trada de forma correta.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
         //comentario..
         /* comentario 2 */

         <title>Design Layout Responsivo</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

<sup>[Imagem do codigo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEK6N.png)</sup>

[image: Saida do trecho do codigo acima]

Comment: Posta seu código fonte ai fazendo favor.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    //comentario..
    /* comentario 2 */

    <title>Design Layout Responsivo</title>
</head>
<body>
   
</body>
</html>

Comment: Provavelmente o problema pode ser é uma aspa que pode estar quebrada no seu código, e por isso o comentário não irá funcionar, nem sempre o problema está no VSCode, pode ser no código, experimente fazer comentário num arquivo em branco e veja se funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Comentários HTML são feitos abrindo a tag `<!--` e fechando em `-->`. Exemplo:

```
 <!-- comentario.. --> 
 <!-- 
      comentario 2
      segunda linha
 -->
```

`//` e `/* */` são para javascript (e outras línguas). Exemplo javascript:

```
<script>
    //comentario..
    /* comentario 2 */
</script>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado....to vindo de outra linguagem rsrs...valeu mesmo

Comment: Se respondeu a pergunta, Marca como resposta.